# classicthesis / A Classic Thesis Style

Tags: xetex, babel, greek, classicthesis

I am trying to use the following LaTeX style that can be seen here [classicthesis / A Classic Thesis Style](https://bitbucket.org/amiede/classicthesis/wiki/Home)

However, I need to configure to accept the **Greek** language. I followed the instructions I found here that apparently allow one to write in **Spanish** [classicthesis / SpanishLanguageSupport](https://bitbucket.org/amiede/classicthesis/wiki/SpanishLanguageSupport), but when i try to do the same with Greek, I get a ton of errors !!!

Any, help or pinpointing to the right direction will be appreciated!!!

Many Thanks,
Viktor

Comment: Please try package `babel`, or posting your working example.

Comment: I would like to thank you all for posting a solution to my problem. I also upvoted your answers, however, because my status is "Newbie", they were recorded but can not be seen. Finally, I kinda knew about the MWE (Minimum Working Example), however, the template was big and with so many files that I did not know which one to upload or where to focus. Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 2):

Since some years, `classicthesis` can use the `book` class.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\usepackage{classicthesis}
\usepackage{substitutefont}
\hypersetup{unicode}

\substitutefont{LGR}{\rmdefault}{artemisia}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

\chapter{Αθήνα}

Η Αθήνα είναι η πρωτεύουσα της Ελλάδας από το 1834 και η μεγαλύτερη πόλη της. 
Βρίσκεται στην Αττική, στην ανατολική Στερεά Ελλάδα, και είναι από τις αρχαιότερες 
πόλεις του κόσμου, με την καταγεγραμμένη ιστορία της να φθάνει ως το 3.200 π.Χ. 
Η Αρχαία Αθήνα, αρχικά οικισμός πάνω στην Ακρόπολη, εξελίχθηκε τον 6ο αιώνα π.Χ. 
σε μία πανίσχυρη πόλη-κράτος, που αναπτύχθηκε παράλληλα με το λιμάνι της, το οποίο 
αρχικά ήταν το Φάληρο και αργότερα ο Πειραιάς. Υπήρξε, κατά την κλασική εποχή, 
κέντρο των τεχνών, της γνώσης και της φιλοσοφίας, έδρα της Ακαδημίας του Πλάτωνα 
και του Λυκείου του Αριστοτέλη. Αναφέρεται ευρέως ως γενέτειρα της δημοκρατίας. 
Συχνά, η Αθήνα, όπως και γενικότερα η Ελλάδα, χαρακτηρίζεται «λίκνο του 
δυτικού πολιτισμού», ενώ άλλες φορές, ο τίτλος αυτός αποδίδεται στη Μεσοποταμία. 
Η σύγχρονη Αθήνα είναι το κέντρο της οικονομικής, βιομηχανικής, πολιτικής και 
πολιτιστικής ζωής της Ελλάδας. Σύμφωνα με την Ευρωπαϊκή Στατιστική Υπηρεσία, 
η Ευρύτερη Αστική Περιοχή της Αθήνας, η οποία ουσιαστικά συμπίπτει με την 
Περιφέρεια Αττικής, είναι η 7η πολυπληθέστερη στην Ευρωπαϊκή Ένωση, με τον 
πληθυσμό της να εκτιμάται το 2004 στους 4.013.368 κατοίκους.

\end{document}
```

You need to substitute the font for Greek, because the standard Palatino font has no support for Greek.

Text is from [https://el.wikipedia.org/wiki/Αθήνα](https://el.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%91%CE%B8%CE%AE%CE%BD%CE%B1)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well, let me say it in this way:

Class `classicthesis` is known to be problematic, it can cause a lot of troubles. For example it uses packages that shoud better not used with KOMA-Script classes `classicthesis` is based of ...

Because I do not speak greek let us use package `blindtext` in the following mwe:

```
\RequirePackage{silence} % :-\
    \WarningFilter{scrreprt}{Usage of package `titlesec'}
    %\WarningFilter{scrreprt}{Activating an ugly workaround}
    \WarningFilter{titlesec}{Non standard sectioning command detected}
\PassOptionsToPackage{greek}{babel} % <=================================
\documentclass[%
  twoside,
  openright,
  titlepage,
  numbers=noenddot,
  headinclude,
  %1headlines,
  footinclude=true,
  cleardoublepage=empty,
  dottedtoc, % Make page numbers in the table of contents flushed right with dots leading to them
  BCOR=5mm,
  paper=a4,
  fontsize=11pt, % Binding correction, paper type and font size
  greek, % <============================================================
]{scrreprt} 

\input{classicthesis-config}

\usepackage{blindtext}


\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{greek} % <==============================================

\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Please see that the usage of package `silence` is to get rid of the warnings resulting in packages better not to use with KOMA-Script.

The resulting pdf of the mwe is then:

[image: resulting pdf]

I got 37  warning messages (warnings are no error messages!) resulting from `blindtext` not knowing greek (perhaps you can help there?) and from issues with the used font.

Both issues I can not solve, because you gave no MWE in your question and I do not know which font you are using writing greek and I can not add all needed greek text to `blindtext`. Perhaps you can help here, that is the part of the documentation of `blindtext` naming what is needed to add greek to it:

[image: docu blindtext]

The documentation you can find with `texdoc blindtext` in your terminal/console, there you find the email to contact the author of that package with needed infos ...

And you can add an mwe to your question with real greek text, showing your used font and resulting in the "tons of errors" you mentioned.

For me it seems you can use greek as I showed you in my mwe, but be aware that template `classicthesis` is known to produce bad surprises for users. If possible, use another template or be aware of other problems comming up soon!